# Map() is not a function even though data is present React-Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I am trying to recreate the React-Leaflet list of markers example. I have an array of objects that I'm sending to `MarkerList` to be turned into Fragments and rendered on the map. However my map function isn't working, using the browser debugging tool I know that the data is there, it's defining `markers` to have the array that I want but I keep getting the error that `markers.map` is not a function. Any nods in the right direction would be helpful.

```
const PopupMarker = content => (
  <Marker position={content.coords}>
    <Popup>{content.applicant}</Popup>
  </Marker>
);

const MarkerList = markers => {
  const items = markers.map(props => (
    <PopupMarker key={markers.id} {...props} />
  ));
  return <Fragment>{items}</Fragment>
};
class MyMap extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array,
  }

  state = {
    lat: 37.7749,
    lng: -122.4194,
    zoom: 13,
  }

  handleMapChange = () => {
    console.log('I work');
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];

    const southWest = L.latLng(37.713159, -122.527084);
    const northEast = L.latLng(37.814666, -122.365723);
    const bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

    return (
      <Map 
        center={position} 
        maxBounds={bounds} 
        zoom={this.state.zoom} 
        style={{height: '30em', width: '75%'}}
        onMoveend={this.handleMapChange}
        onZoomend={this.handleMapChange}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {data !== null &&
          <MarkerList markers={data} />
        }
      </Map>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `data` is obviously not an array. You don't show how your instantiating `MyMap`, so there's no way for us to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const MarkerList = markers => {`

TO

`const MarkerList = {markers} => {`

You need to access *(by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) how I've implemented)* the `markers` property of the `props` object you're passing to `<MarkerList>` component. This will give you the value of `data` that you assigned to it `markers={data}`. Right now you're trying to `map()` over the [`props`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-in-jsx) argument, which is an Object not an Array.

But looking at your code further you likely need to rewrite this function entirely...

```
const MarkerList = markers => {
  const items = markers.map(props => (
    <PopupMarker key={markers.id} {...props} />
  ));
  return <Fragment>{items}</Fragment>
};
```

To something like ...

```
const MarkerList = {markers} => {
  const items = markers.map({id, ...rest} => (
    <PopupMarker key={id} {...rest} />
  ));
  return <Fragment>{items}</Fragment>
};
```

Given that we don't know the shape of the `makers` data I can't be positive this is the right solution, but one thing is for sure, if `markers` is an Array you won't be able to access the `id` property on it (`markers.id`).

Comment: This is just what I needed thanks, I had tried it this way but eslint wasn't having it. I just had to throw some parenthesis around the brackets and voila! const MarkerList = ({markers}) =>

Answer (score 0):

In the render() method, you should handle the case when data is null. EX:

```
render() {
const { data } = this.props;
const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];

const southWest = L.latLng(37.713159, -122.527084);
const northEast = L.latLng(37.814666, -122.365723);
const bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
if(!data) { 
  return null;
}
return (
  <Map 
    center={position} 
    maxBounds={bounds} 
    zoom={this.state.zoom} 
    style={{height: '30em', width: '75%'}}
    onMoveend={this.handleMapChange}
    onZoomend={this.handleMapChange}
  >
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <MarkerList markers={data} />
  </Map>
)
```

}